# {"message":"Cannot GET /","error":"Not Found","statusCode":404} nestjs typeorm error

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I did the setup completely according to the documentation in a clean project and nothing works for me. I don’t understand what the error is related to and in which direction to move to solve it

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';

@Module({
  imports: [UsersModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'root1',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'test2',
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

user.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';
import { UsersController } from './users.controller';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  providers: [UsersService],
  controllers: [UsersController],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { CreateUserDto } from './dto/create-user.dto';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly usersRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    const user = new User();
    user.firstName = createUserDto.firstName;
    user.lastName = createUserDto.lastName;

    return this.usersRepository.save(user);
  }

  async findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.usersRepository.find();
  }

  findOne(id: number): Promise<User> {
    return this.usersRepository.findOneBy({ id: id });
  }

  async remove(id: string): Promise<void> {
    await this.usersRepository.delete(id);
  }
}
```

users.service.spec.ts

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

const userArray = [
  {
    firstName: 'firstName #1',
    lastName: 'lastName #1',
  },
  {
    firstName: 'firstName #2',
    lastName: 'lastName #2',
  },
];

const oneUser = {
  firstName: 'firstName #1',
  lastName: 'lastName #1',
};

describe('UserService', () => {
  let service: UsersService;
  let repository: Repository<User>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        UsersService,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
          useValue: {
            find: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(userArray),
            findOneBy: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(oneUser),
            save: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(oneUser),
            remove: jest.fn(),
            delete: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<UsersService>(UsersService);
    repository = module.get<Repository<User>>(getRepositoryToken(User));
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('create()', () => {
    it('should successfully insert a user', () => {
      const oneUser = {
        firstName: 'firstName #1',
        lastName: 'lastName #1',
      };

      expect(
        service.create({
          firstName: 'firstName #1',
          lastName: 'lastName #1',
        }),
      ).resolves.toEqual(oneUser);
    });
  });

  describe('findAll()', () => {
    it('should return an array of users', async () => {
      const users = await service.findAll();
      expect(users).toEqual(userArray);
    });
  });

  describe('findOne()', () => {
    it('should get a single user', () => {
      const repoSpy = jest.spyOn(repository, 'findOneBy');
      expect(service.findOne(1)).resolves.toEqual(oneUser);
      expect(repoSpy).toBeCalledWith({ id: 1 });
    });
  });

  describe('remove()', () => {
    it('should call remove with the passed value', async () => {
      const removeSpy = jest.spyOn(repository, 'delete');
      const retVal = await service.remove('2');
      expect(removeSpy).toBeCalledWith('2');
      expect(retVal).toBeUndefined();
    });
  });
});
```

users.controller.ts

```
import {
    Body,
    Controller,
    Delete,
    Get,
    Param,
    Post,
    ParseIntPipe,
  } from '@nestjs/common';
  import { CreateUserDto } from './dto/create-user.dto';
  import { User } from './user.entity';
  import { UsersService } from './users.service';
  
  @Controller('users')
  export class UsersController {
    constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}
  
    @Post()
    create(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
      return this.usersService.create(createUserDto);
    }
  
    @Get()
    findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
      return this.usersService.findAll();
    }
  
    @Get(':id')
    findOne(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number): Promise<User> {
      return this.usersService.findOne(id);
    }
  
    @Delete(':id')
    remove(@Param('id') id: string): Promise<void> {
      return this.usersService.remove(id);
    }
  }
```

user.entity.ts

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ default: true })
  isActive: boolean;
}
```

I can’t even start a test project with nestjs typeorm from GitHub. Maybe my database settings are incorrect? Or project config file

Comment: Please share the errors you get, or specific question; This would help focus the answer.